# Unity Firebase not working when no sim card inserted

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firebase with Unity 2018.1.3
My app is just basic data transfer using Firebase connection.

Running on Unity Game player is working fine, but when I export .apk to a physical Android device with no sim card inserted, it is not working.
However, when I insert the sim card, it would work.

I don't know why the sim card insert or not will affect the connection of Firebase.
It is very weird.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you connected to Wifi? Does the Wifi connection work well? Are you forcing firebase to use cellular data only? Just to sort some obvious mistakes out...

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco Thanks for your reply. Of course I have WiFi connection for both sim card cases. Where can I change the firebase cellular data configuration?

Comment: Its more like you have to restrict it from using wifi, if you haven't then there's not a problem.

Comment: Maybe it's a network problem, your wifi may not be able to connect to Google's firebase servers, try doing a ping test to them from that network.

Comment: Found this https://www.firebase.com/test.html

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco I used the same WiFi network instead of cellular data when I inserted sim card, but it works. Today I tried another device also have the same issue.

Comment: I just tested once again, it works fine without sim card. This is so weird. I have 100% sure the previous tests were using the same WiFi connection. but it works now, I really don't know the reason.